# Bisect Tool Distorting Mesh

Tags: mesh, knife-tool, bisect

I'm trying to paint striping around this .stp locomotive model. I've previously done color separations using either the bisect or knife tools to define the boundary, but on this rounded surface it's completely distorting and "denting" the curves. is there another way to apply the striping without the warping?

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, instead of changing the topology you could simply use a black and white image as a mask between 2 colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Bisect* seems to be interacting unfavourably with heavily triangulated topology, disrupting the interpolation of normals. If you wanted to cut the model cleanly, its topology would have to follow the contours in the surface it represents more closely.

In any case, it would be more typical, and more flexible, to apply your stripes using a material. Here's a shot at a reasonable interface to a 'Z Stripes' procedural mask (which assumes your model is Z-up):

[image]

Which can be used to mix your paint:

[image]

Thus:

[image]

[image]

But if you wanted other livery, including, say, logos or labels, it would probably be better to include the stripes in a more broadly detailed UV map (or maps) of the surface, suitably projected.